# How to create a new column based on other columns in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

```
DT0 = data.table(x=rep(c(NA,NA,NA)), y=c(0,1,NA), v=c(0, 0, NA), l=c(1,1,1))
DT0
#    x  y  v l
#1: NA  0  0 1
#2: NA  1  0 1
#3: NA NA NA 1
```

Based on the first three cols `x`, `y` and `v` I want to add a new col with following output

```
#1:  No
#2: Yes
#3:  NA
```

`NA` if all rows are `NA`. `Yes` if any of them is `1` else `0`. My current approach is

```
relevant_cols <- c('x', 'y', 'v')
new <- data.table(apply(DT0[, relevant_cols, with=F], 1, function(val) { ifelse(all(is.na(val)), NA_character_, ifelse(any(val == TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), 'Yes', 'No')) }))
DT0[, new:= new]
DT0
#    x  y  v l new
#1: NA  0  0 1  No
#2: NA  1  0 1 Yes
#3: NA NA NA 1  NA
```

However, as the actual `data.table` is large, is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:**
Often the data.table entries are non-numeric hence it would be quite helpful if I can have a more general solution than using `pmax` `e.g.`,

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c(NA,NA,NA)), y=c('No','Yes',NA), v=c('No', 'No', NA), l=c(1,1,1))
DT
#    x  y     v l
#1: NA  No   No 1
#2: NA  Yes  No 1
#3: NA NA    NA 1
```

Comment: Like `do.call(pmax, c(DT[,x:v,with=FALSE], na.rm=TRUE))`, but relabeled? Or do you have some non-0/1 entries?

Comment: Thanks @Frank. Is there a similar solution if the entries are non numeric (edited data.table).

Comment: We could have some fun with `rowSums` as in `DT[, rowSums(.SD == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) *NA^(rowSums(is.na(.SD)) == .N), .SDcols = -"l"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
DT[, new := ifelse(rowSums(.SD == "Yes", na.rm = T) > 0,
                   'Yes',
                   ifelse(rowSums(is.na(.SD)) != ncol(.SD), "No", NA))
   , .SDcols = x:v]
#    x   y  v l new
#1: NA  No No 1  No
#2: NA Yes No 1 Yes
#3: NA  NA NA 1  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

`pmax` is pretty well-suited to this problem.

**First example**  In the 0/1 case...

```
DT0[, do.call(pmax, c(na.rm=TRUE, .SD)), .SDcols=x:v]
# 0 1 NA
```

**Second example** If you've encoded 0/1 as `my_lvls = c("No","Yes")` instead...

```
DT[, 
  factor(
    labels = my_lvls,
    x      = do.call(pmax, c(na.rm=TRUE, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
               as.integer(factor(x, levels=my_lvls)))))
  )
, .SDcols=x:v]
# [1] No   Yes  <NA>
# Levels: No Yes
```

As shown in @eddi's answer, to add a new col, you can put the `x:v` in `.SDcols` and use `.SD`.

Comment: Not very often I get an excuse to write five `)`s in a row... there must be a better way, though I'm not fond of coercing with row/colSums.