# How to retrieve column for row-wise maximum value in an R data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, max

I have the following R data.table:

```
library(data.table)
iris = as.data.table(iris)
> iris
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
...
```

Let's say I wanted to find the row-wise maximum value by each row, only for the subset of data.table columns: `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`

I would use the following code:

```
iris[, maximum_element :=max(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width), by=1:nrow(iris)]
```

Which outputs

```
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species     maximum_element
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa               5.1
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa               4.9
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa               4.7
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa               4.6
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa               5.0
```

For my problem, I'm actually not interested in the value, but which column the value came from, i.e. I would like the following output:

```
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species maximum_column
      1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa  Sepal.Length
      2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa  Sepal.Length
      3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa  Sepal.Length
      4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa  Sepal.Length
      5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa  Sepal.Length
```

(In this case, the max. value each comes from `Sepal.Length`).

How do I "retrieve" the column name with the maximum value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909684/calculate-row-wise-maximum/28910623#28910623) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768847/how-to-create-a-new-column-based-on-other-columns-in-a-data-table/33769378#33769378)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an option with `pmax`

```
iris[, maximum_element := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = 1:4]
```

---

and to find the column names, use `max.col` on `.SD` after specifying the `.SDcols` as the numeric columns, i.e. columns 1 to 4

```
iris[,maximum_column :=  names(.SD)[max.col(.SD)], .SDcols = 1:4]
head(iris, 4)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species maximum_column
#1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   Sepal.Length
#2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   Sepal.Length
#3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   Sepal.Length
#4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   Sepal.Length
```

Comment: This is a silly question, what is the correct way to find the column number to use `.SDcols`? That is, a user knows they want everything from `Sepal.Length` to `Petal.Width`

Comment: @Shan `.SDcols = Sepal.Length:Petal.Width` should work. Otherwise, you could look at `match(x, names(DT))` or similar.